# Preventing page reflow due to image loading, while also imposing a max-width on the said images (HTML/CSS only)

Tags: html, css

I want to prevent page-reflow, caused by image loading on a web page.

Page reflow occurs when images load after the page's text content has already rendered. There's a 'jerk' caused by the said page-reflow. It makes for awful user experience.

My requirements are:

- (i) All images be fully responsive
- (ii) Have a max-width of 450px (while maintaining aspect-ratio)
- (iii) Be center-aligned within their containers

There can be several images on the page. All have different aspect ratios (but scaled to the same width - i.e. 450px). I know their dimensions beforehand.

---

Currently my code is simply:

```css
    .container {
          text-align:center;
          overflow:hidden;
          background:whitesmoke;
          border-top:1px solid #F0F0F0;
          border-bottom:1px solid #F0F0F0;
        }
    
.container img {
          width:100%;
          max-width:450px;
          vertical-align: top;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
    <img src="https://s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/damadam-2019/public/31a1b420-59c9-405a-a197-e04dd1e2eaf9.jpg" alt="image">
</div>
```

This fulfils all my requirements - except it can't prevent page reflow. How do I tweak this to get my desired result?

---

Traditional solutions to prevent such page-reflow go something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/damadam-2019/public/31a1b420-59c9-405a-a197-e04dd1e2eaf9.jpg" alt="image">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: calc(100%/(450/562));/* example width=450px height=562px*/
  height: 0;
}

.container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

This works fine. But it doesn't impose a `max-width` like I need it to. The image fills the entire container - as large as that container is (e.g. the full width of the screen on a laptop).

To tweak it, I tried adding `max-width:450px;max-height:562px` in `.container img`. That corrected the image's dimensions. But it gave the container extra padding at the bottom:

[image]

That's a shame. What I really wanted was for it to look like below:

[image]

Note that the gray colouration above is the background container, which simply disappears on smaller resolutions:

[image]

What's the best way for me to achieve my requirements? An illustrative example would be great.

*Note: adding `max-width: 450px;max-height: 561px;` in `.container` doesn't solve the problem either.*